# Work with PhpStorm, github.com for little web studio?

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

We are little web studio (4 people) which create web sites use WordPress and Magento!

We want use github.com, currently choosing logic for github.com.
I created some prototype, can you give me feedback what I can improve in my scheme, maybe I need change something or remove and create something another.

Picture with my logic **Fork -> Permissions -> Checkout -> Production**:

[image: **Fork -> Permissions -> Checkout -> Production**]

Thank you for your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid workflow, why not?

Give it a try, and adjust if it doesn't fit your needs.

What you have is somewhat similar to [Git Flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/). Perhaps, forks are not needed here, feature branches in same repo could do the work for you.

You can keep all the rights and permission in the same repo, by using [protected branches](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/) (if you repo is in the organization, you can define [users who can merge](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/) to `production` branch)